# Comparing Ranges in Excel

Tags: .net, excel-interop

In the Excel Interop libraries, is there functionality to determine whether a given `Range` object is contained within another `Range` object?

It would be simple enough for me to compare the row and column indices of each `Range`, but things become more complicated when you want to compare two ranges that may be on different worksheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Intersect` will do the job.

It will give you a Range that is the intersection of two ranges A and B

If Range A is contained in Range B, then the result will have the same width and height as A.

The result will be null / Nothing if the ranges don't intersect at all.